# Анимация заголовка вдоль края страницы

Tags: javascript, jquery

В учебнике написана задача:

> Создайте собственную анимацию.   Используйте `setInterval` для
>   анимации заголовка `h1`, двигая его по квадрату вдоль краев страницы.

Текст двигаю вправо и вниз, а дальше никак, помогите начинающему

```js
var leftOffset = 0;
var topOffset = 0;
 
var moveHeading = function () {
  $("#heading").offset({ 
    left: leftOffset,
    top: topOffset
  });
  leftOffset++;
  if (leftOffset > 200) {
    leftOffset = 200;

    topOffset++;
    if (topOffset > 200) {
      topOffset = 200;
    }
  } 
};


setInterval(moveHeading, 30)
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>move</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Привет, мир!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот работающий пример

```html
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>move</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h1 id="heading">Привет, мир!</h1>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
 <script>



var leftOffset = 0;
var topOffset = 0;
var dir = "right";

var moveHeading = function () {$("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset,                        top: topOffset})
if(dir == "right")    
leftOffset++;
else
leftOffset--;
if(leftOffset < 0 && topOffset > 0)
{
 leftOffset = 0;
 topOffset--;
}
else if(topOffset == 0)
{
 dir = "right";
}
if (leftOffset > 200) {
leftOffset = 200;

topOffset++;
if (topOffset > 200) {
 topOffset =200;
 dir = "left";
 }
 else if(topOffset < 0)
 {
 topOffset =0;
 }
 } 
 };


 setInterval(moveHeading, 30)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: большое спасибо, для начинающего все ясно и понятно

Answer (score 2):

У текста есть 4 состояния(направления движения), которые нужно переключать.
Также, чтобы анимация выглядела равномерной, нужно высчитывать величину сдвига в зависимости от прошедшего времени.

```js
var start = Date.now(); // Время начала анимации
var leftOffset = 0;     // Начальное положение
var topOffset = 0;
var direction = 'r';    // Начальное направление
var pixPerSec = 300;    // Скорость анимации
var leftLimit = $(document).width() - $('#heading').width();  // Границы, с учётом размера элемента(чтобы не появлялся скролл, или элемент не выходил за рамки документа)
var topLimit = $(document).height() - $('#heading').height();
 
var moveHeading = function () {
  var now = Date.now(); // Текущее время
  var step = pixPerSec*(now - start) / 1e3; // На сколько пикселей нужно сдвинуть элемент
  
  // Сама анимация
  $("#heading").offset({ 
    left: leftOffset,
    top: topOffset
  });
  
  // Что делать дальше?
  
  switch (direction) {
   case 'r':
     // Прибавляем шаг в текущем направлении
     leftOffset += step;
     // Если достигли границы,
     if (leftOffset > leftLimit) {
       // Не даём элементы выйти за неё
       leftOffset = leftLimit;
       // Меняем направление
       direction = 'd';
     }
     break;
   case 'd':
     topOffset += step;
     if (topOffset > topLimit) {
       topOffset = topLimit;
       direction = 'l';
     }
     break;
   case 'l':
     leftOffset -= step;
     if (leftOffset < 0) {
       leftOffset = 0;
       direction = 'u';
     }
     break;
   case 'u':
     topOffset -= step;
     if (topOffset < 0) {
       topOffset = 0;
       direction = 'r';
     }
     break;
  }
  // Сбрасываем время на текущий момент  
  start = now;
};


setInterval(moveHeading, 30)
```

```css
h1{display: inline-block; margin: 0;}
body{background-color: #eee;}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>move</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Привет, мир!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: нужно еще дорасти до Вашего ответа, попробую разобраться спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>собственная анимация (квадрат)</title> 
    <style>
    * {
        margin: 0; 
        padding: 0;
    }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h1 id="heading">Hello world</h1>
<script>
    var leftOffSet = 0; 
    var topOffSet = 0; 
    function moveHeading () {
        if (leftOffSet < 200 && topOffSet <= 0) {
            $("#heading").offset({left: leftOffSet++}); 
            
        } else if (leftOffSet >= 200 && topOffSet < 200) {
            $("#heading").offset({top: topOffSet++}); 

        } else if (leftOffSet > 0 && topOffSet >= 200) {
            $("#heading").offset({left: leftOffSet--});
            
        } else if (leftOffSet <= 0 && topOffSet > 0) {
            $("#heading").offset({top: topOffSet--});
        }
        
    }; 
    setInterval(moveHeading, 30);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Answer (score 0):

Я делал так

```
let offSetLeft = 0
let offSetTop = 0

var moveheading = function() {
    if (offSetLeft < 200 && offSetTop === 0) {
        $('#heading').offset({ left : offSetLeft, top : offSetTop})
        offSetLeft++
    } else if (offSetLeft === 200 && offSetTop < 200 ) {
        $('#heading').offset({ top : offSetTop})
        offSetTop++
    } else if (offSetTop >= 200 && offSetLeft != 0 ) {
        $('#heading').offset({ left : offSetLeft})
        offSetLeft--
    } else  {
        $('#heading').offset({ top : offSetTop})
        offSetTop--
    }

}

var moveTitle = setInterval(moveheading, 30)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var leftOffset1 = 0;
var leftOffset2 = 200;
var topOffset1 = 0;
var topOffset2 = 200;


function moveHeading1() 
{
  if (leftOffset1 < 200)
  {
    $("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset1 });
    leftOffset1++;
    
  }
  else
  {
    $("#heading").offset({top: topOffset1});
    topOffset1++;
  }
  
  if ( topOffset1 > 200)
  {
    topOffset1 = 200;
    leftOffset1 = 200;
     $("#heading").offset({ left: leftOffset2 });
     leftOffset2 --;
  }
   if(leftOffset2 < 0)
   {
    leftOffset2 = 0;
    $("#heading").offset({ top: topOffset2 });
    topOffset2--;
   }
  if (topOffset2 < 0)
  {
    topOffset2 = 200;
    leftOffset2 = 200;
    topOffset1 = 0;
    leftOffset1 = 0;
  }
  
  
   
};
setInterval(moveHeading1, 1)
```

```html
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>move</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1 id="heading">Привет, мир!</h1>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Я позаимствовал твой код и доработал его. Время потратил не мало, но получилось. Я старался делать как учит Ник Морган. Морган не рассказывал что можно использовать swith или направление.